Mapping ESC sequences doesn't work
I'm using wezterm to forward Shift keypresses in the combination CTRL+SHIFT+c to nvim. This is my conf:
...
{
    key = 'c',
    mods = 'CTRL|SHIFT',
    action = wezterm.action_callback(function(win, pane)
        if pane:is_alt_screen_active() then
            win:perform_action(act.SendString("\x1b[99;5u"), pane)
            -- win:perform_action(act.SendString("iHello nvim!\r"), pane)
        else
        end
    end),
},
...

I'm quite certain this configuration works, since when uncommenting the iHello nvim SendString line, it will correctly inject "Hello nvim" in an open nvim buffer. So I assume this also happens with the escape sequence.
However, neither one of these mappings work:
map('n', '<C-S-c>', 'iHello nvim!<CR>', { noremap = true })

or
map('n', '<Esc>[99;5u', 'iHello nvim!<CR>', { noremap = true })

What could be the issue?
EDIT: Essentially I'm asking how to make use of the <C-S-..> S (for shift) modifier in nvim. How does nvim usually detect it and how can I cater to it?

You cannot map escape sequences. Only Key combinations.

@ChristianBrabandt Ok fair enough, but how then does nvim internally handle the <C-S-..> (control+SHIFT ..) keystrokes? Shift is usually not sent via tty afaik.

you need to find out how the key is detected. E.g. you type C-V followed by your key sequence in insert mode and see if Vim/Nvim detects your key or not. If not, then it may not be universally possible (at least in your environment). Might be different using other terminals, or the GUI etc

@ChristianBrabandt So you're saying nvim provides a <C-S-..> mapping only for those "environments" that support it? What does my environment need to meet these requirements then?

With Environment I mean a combination of terminal and underlying libraries that is able to recognize your desired key combinations. Note that terminal key combinations are not universal portable accross all systems and it also depends on the support of your terminal for xterm-modifier-keys or the kitty keyboard protocol

@ChristianBrabandt Ok but what then is NVim's default for recognising shift keycombos? I figure there must be a default since the <C-S-..> syntax hints in this direction?

I don't know You should mention what terminal you are using.

@ChristianBrabandt wezterm? Wrote it in OP ^^

I have no idea about wezterm.
